# Image doesn't appear and whole page goes blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to build a React homepage, I already have a header, and I try to import a .png photo, but when i do so with the code below, my header dissapears, the image doesn't show up, and the whole page is blank, what i'm doing wrong?

Homepage component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactComponent as Arrow} from '../../assets/increase.svg'
import QuestionMark from '../../assets/question2.png'
import './homepage.styles.scss';

const HomePage = () => (
  <div className='homepage'>
      <div className='question-mark-container'>
      <QuestionMark className='question-mark'/>
      </div>
      
  </div>
);

export default HomePage;
```

Homepage component styles:

```
.homepage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 80px;

    .question-mark-container{
        height: 60%;
        width: 30vw;
        padding: 25px;
    }
}
```

I don;t think that my router is relevant for this question ,but will post if necessary

Comment: If the page is going blank, that usually means you have an error in your console explaining why.

Comment: You might consider to give a bit more information about your app since from what you have posted here it is simply impossible to find out what is wrong. Is your `HomePage` component the main component within your app? What does the console output say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use png file directly instead use it in img tag:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactComponent as Arrow} from '../../assets/increase.svg'
import QuestionMark from '../../assets/question2.png'
import './homepage.styles.scss';

const HomePage = () => (
  <div className='homepage'>
      <div className='question-mark-container'>
      <img src={QuestionMark} className='question-mark' />
      </div>          
  </div>
);

export default HomePage;
```